# Power BI DISTINCCOUNT if asset comes in contract after certain date

Tags: powerbi, distinct, measure

I am trying to calculate overall percentages and I have got contract A (e.g. 150 assets) and contract B (e.g. 50 assets) as slicer. For this, I need to first add a measure that calculates number of assets

Now within A and B, different assets come in at different dates and more assets come in regularly.

I have got a measure to calculate total number of assets:

***No of assets = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Asset List'[Asset]), ALL('Date Table'))***

The 'ALL' filter prevents picking only assets with data for the month and gives out all the assets for subsequent percentage calculation. I have to do distinct count as there are duplicates as well.

How can I add a filter to show, for example, 200 assets in June 2020 and 201 assets in July 2020 because an asset was added to contract B on 02/07/2020 (now 51 assets)? In the *'Asset List'* table, I have got a column which as contract *In contract date.*

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, No of assets measures could be defined as a simple COUNTROWS() if you were to create a Flag in the backend on Asset List table which is equal to 1 if it is the first time the asset appear in the table and 0 otherwise. Secondly, if an asset appears in both June 2020 and July 2020, should it count as 1 in June 2020 and 1 in July 2020 or what other logic?

Comment: Hi Seymour. Thanks for Replying.

Yes, it should be 1 in both months. So if I had 200 assets in June, one more asset got added start of July and hence, there will will 201 in July.

Comment: Then removing the ALL('Date Table') shoud allow you to combine the measure in a table and split it by 'Date Table'[Year Month].